# ODATA template in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wcf-data-services, odata

I don't see a OData (or WCF data service, or ADO.NET service) template in visual studio 2010. Am I missing something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create a new ASP.NET application, you can add to it a WCF Data Service, which should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

These are the templates you need:

1. New Project => Visual C# Templates => ASP.NET Empty Web Application
2. Add an item to the new project => Visual C# Templates => ADO.NET Entity Data Model
3. Add an item to the new project => Visual C# Templates => Web => WCF Data Service

Answer (score 1):

You can install [WCF Data Services for OData](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306). Doing this willl add a WCF Data Service (for OData) template under the Web tab of VS2010.